# Problems with gravitational N-body simulation

Tags: python, cython, physics

**Background**
I am writing a simple N-body simulation code in Python, with core physics solvers such as acceleration and position integration implemented in Cython. The code uses the leapfrog method to integrate the positions.

**Conditions**

1. Masses: 10, 100 for 2 bodies; 1 for all bodies for number of bodies > 2.
2. Position: Randomly generated
3. Velocity: Randomly generated
4. Timestep: 1e-3

**The bug**

1. For number of bodies > 2: The bodies repel each other instead of attracting each other.
2. For number of bodies = 2: They do not orbit each other but instead travel in straight lines.
3. General bug (regardless of number of bodies): **Repulsive forces**

**Expected behavior**

1. Two bodies must orbit each other
2. The forces must be attractive

**Efforts to resolve the bug**

1. Negative sign for acceleration
2. Multiply acceleration by -1
3. Add a new temporary expression

**Code**
Acceleration function (Cython):

```
def acceleration(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] pos, np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] mass):
cdef int N = pos.shape[0] # Number of bodies   
# Memoryview for acceleration
cdef np.float64_t [:,:] acc = np.zeros((N,3),dtype="float64")
cdef double soft = 1e-4 # Softening length
cdef G = 6.673e-11 # Gravitational constant
# Pairwise separations
cdef double dx
cdef double dy
cdef double dz
# Total separation vectors
cdef double r
cdef double tmp
# Mass
cdef mj
# Acceleration calculation loop
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        # Remove gravitational self forces
        if i==j:
            continue
        
        # Calculate pairwise separation vectors
        dx = pos[j,0] - pos[i,0]
        dy = pos[j,1] - pos[i,1]
        dz = pos[j,2] - pos[i,2]

        # Vector magnitude of separation vector
        r = dx**2 + dy**2 + dz**2
        r = np.sqrt(r)

        # Mass
        mj = mass[j]

        tmp = G * mj * r**3

        # Calculate accelerations
        acc[i,0] += tmp * dx
        acc[i,1] += tmp * dy
        acc[i,2] += tmp * dz

return np.asarray(acc)
```

Position integration:

```
def leapfrog(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] pos, np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] vel, np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] acc, np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] mass):
cdef double dt = 1e-3 # Timestep

# The Leapfrog integration method
# v(t+1/2) = v(t) + a(t) x dt/2
# x(t+1) = x(t) + v(t+1/2) x dt
# a(t+1) = (G * m/((dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2)^(3/2))) * dx * x
# v(t+1) = v(t+1/2) + a(t+1) x dt/2
vel += acc * dt/2
pos += vel * dt
acc = acceleration(pos, mass)
vel += acc * dt/2

return pos, acc
```

Main simulation loop (Python):
for _ in range(Nt):
# Calculate positions and get new acceleration values
pos, acc = leapfrog(pos, vel, acc, m)

Plot (Python):

```
plt.scatter(pos_arr[:,0], pos_arr[:,1])
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Refer to the images for more info regarding the bug:

[image: Bug_picture_2D]

Two bodies repelling each other + moving in a straight line instead of orbiting

[image: Bug_picture_3D]

3D View of the bug.

**Edit 1**: Velocity = 0
Here is the result with velocity = 0 (vel = np.zeros((N,3)), where N=2.
The red point is the first element of the position array and the green point is the last point.

[image: Velocity=0 result]

**Edit 2: tmp * dx/2** :
This is the result obtained by dividing the separation vectors by r.
Updated code:

```
acc[i,0] += tmp * dx/r
acc[i,1] += tmp * dy/r
acc[i,2] += tmp * dz/r
```

[image: tmp*dx/r]

**Edit 3: velocity = 1e-6**
This is what the result looks like for setting both velocities = 1e-6. They remain stationary.

[image: v=1e-6]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! I deleted a couple of comments here because (A) they were very rudely phrased, and (B) they contained some misunderstandings. [No one is expected to leave a comment when they vote on a post here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436), whether they upvote or downvote. Voting is not rude nor a personal attack; it is merely how content is rated. Please hover your mouse pointer over the vote buttons to see what each type of vote means. Furthermore, all votes are anonymous, so [you've no way of knowing who downvoted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388686).

Comment: My first guess would be that you've set your initial velocity so high enough that the particles end up well separated before you see any effect of your force. What this question is missing is an [mre] - i.e. it should be possible for someone to reproduce your graphs on their PC. You aren't far off, but we definitely don't know the starting conditions

Comment: @DavidW Thanks for responding! I will try to add an MWE. The initial conditions are very simple: I used np.random.randn to generate the initial conditions: `pos  = np.random.randn(N,3), 
vel  = np.random.randn(N,3)`.

Comment: Try with `vel = np.zeros(N,3)` - they should head straight through each other. But it's probably the simplest way of checking that they do attract.

Comment: @DavidW : I made an edit outlining velocities = 0 using np.zeros((N,3)). Here is the result: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGIXh.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGIXh.png) (I can't display it because some "person" reduced my reputation by downvoting this question). The red point is the first row of the array (position[0,:]) and the green point is the last row of the array (position[-1,:]).

Comment: That graph looks like it might be right to me: the particles are attracted to each other and then return. Try with really small initial velocities (maybe `1e-6`?) and then increase them slowly until you see some change in behaviour.

Comment: in `def acceleration` , the `tmp` acceleration vector should be broken down into its x,y,z component before it can be applied to `mi`.. right?

Comment: (imfo) if `mi*tmp = G*mi*mj/r**2` is the original equation.. then `* r**3` should be `/ r**2` right? | please correct me if the derivation/equation is different..

Comment: Suggested correction : `acc[i,0] += tmp * dx` become `acc[i,0] += tmp * dx/r` (same for the other 2 vector)

Comment: @p._phidot_ Thank you for your comment! I added the result obtained by dividing the separation vectors by r to my question (see edit 2). Is this what one might expect? For me, this is pretty unexpected as the bodies do not orbit.

Comment: @DavidW I followed your advice and updated the velocities to 1e-6. I added the result to the question (edit 3). The bodies don't move at all, which is kind of weird: They move when v = 0, but remain stationary when v=1e-6. What do you think about this? Is this correct?

Comment: Is the `* r**3` vs `/ r**2` checked ?

Comment: @p._phidot_ Yes, and it seems correct. However, when I implement ` / r**2` I still don't get an orbit, only straight-line motion. [Here is the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsJGz.png).

Comment: @Astro my direction of troubleshooting is more like [ Is the algo correct ? ] first & [ is there any error in the code? ] later.. all my question / concerns resolves around that.. | You had shared the the output from each edit, but do we have a sample output for a defined in put?

Comment: Gravitational force is relatively very small force, thus need to iterate over a lot (I mean a whole LOT) of [time](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=1+year+in+seconds&ia=answer), [distance](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=earth+sun+distance) & [mass difference ratio](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=earth+mass%2Fsun+mass) to see them orbit. I cannot see the value of mass applied to the objects(mi mj values), or the time scale (or number of iteration) so I didn't comment on that. But the given plot gave me a sense that the space is relatively small (< 1km).

Comment: My point is, use a hand calculated output for simple case (2 mass, 2D space, very big mass difference), simple setup (eg both static >> they should collide, big mass1 static mass2 moving at tangent direction >> velocity direction should change). You may use have a sun/merciry(or earth) model, use their mass, position & [velocity](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=mercury+velocity) (at a direction tangent to their line up) applied, run the model for 100 days(8640000 s) see if the output is comparable..

Comment: @p._phidot_ I made *big* changes to the code. Please visit the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Kushaalkumar-pothula/gravitylab) to see the changes. Also, please clone my repo and experiment with it to see what is going wrong. Thank you so much for helping me so far!

Comment: Good job on the revision.. that is.. quite different than the code posted here.. (I'm still learning how to clone ur project.. ) Meanwhile... I did notice that you had also change the `def acceleration()` .. Can you please share the references/link for the calculation method at line 90-107 of `solvers.pyx` ?

Comment: @p._phidot_ I got the acceleration function form [here](https://github.com/danieljprice/galaxy/blob/7dd4ff415cc364c8438693607227fc3b5f3c0688/galaxy.py#L104).

Comment: @p._phidot_ I made my project [available on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/GravityLab/). However, there have been issues importing the package after installing with `pip`, because the module `solvers` is not being imported, despite including a SO file. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Sorry I didn't help much. After seeing the code, I realize that you are learning something big.. (I vouch for that..) On the other hand.. while reading ur revised code, I'm still focusing on the algo part, apparently (thanks for the link. (I really appreciate it. Really do.)) It is legit, but no details of its derivation (which what I'm looking for..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved: using a better acceleration algorithm solved the problem. The code is now available at [GitHub](https://github.com/Kushaalkumar-pothula/gravitylab). The only problem now is to animate the plot. Please let me know how to animate it in the comments. Thanks for the help all along!

Here are the results of a two-body simulation:

[image: 2body]

Comment: Congratulations on the solution found.. Nice work btw.. | as for the qustion.. you may just post it as another question (with details focusing on just that).. | nice gfx btw.

Comment: @p._phidot_ thanks! I will try to post a question. Thanks for the help again!

Comment: The ref author used [ffmpeg](https://github.com/danieljprice/galaxy/blob/7dd4ff415cc364c8438693607227fc3b5f3c0688/galaxy.py#L206) to get an mp4 out of the generated frames.. (just a proposal/ref) /(^_^)

Comment: I tried to [follow his technique](https://github.com/Kushaalkumar-pothula/gravitylab/blob/c28acf6b5ed658b4757739a950293963176face3/gravitylab/simulate.py#L116) but all I get are errors and a blank figure. Please help me out with this if possible.

Comment: [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) the uestion.. with his code vs ur tries (plus other method looked u'd research).. see how others help/comment ( : –